# Error when replacing body element from SOAP request in SOAPHandler

Tags: java, jax-ws, soaphandler

I use a velocity template to create a soap request.
I use the jax-ws framework to implement a web service client.
I have wired a SOAP Handler to intercept outbound messages.

I am trying to replace the body content by a new body computed.

I use the following code in my handler:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    try {
        if (outbound) {
            SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
            SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
            body.normalize();
            System.out.println(body.getValue());
            NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("template");
            if(list.getLength() > 0) {
                Element template = (Element) list.item(0);
                if (template != null) {
                    String newBody = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(template.getTextContent());
                    Document bodyElement = XmlUtils.getDocumentFromText(newBody);
                    body.removeContents();
                    body.addDocument(bodyElement);
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

How can I change the body content from in an xml text without too much hassle?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I dig way more and it turns out I found the solution. Here is the code:

```
SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
            SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
            body.normalize();
            System.out.println(body.getValue());
            NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("template");
            if(list.getLength() > 0) {
                Element template = (Element) list.item(0);
                if (template != null) {
                    String newBody = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(template.getTextContent());
                    Document bodyElement = XmlUtils.getBody(newBody);
                    body.removeContents();
                    body.addDocument(bodyElement);
```

More important, the method XmlUtils.getBody:

```
public static Document getBody(String fromText) {
    Document result = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        result = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(fromText.getBytes()));
        NodeList list = result.getElementsByTagNameNS("soapenv", "Body");
        if(list.getLength() > 0) {
            Node body = list.item(0);
            result = builder.newDocument();
            result.adoptNode(body);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I was actually the `factory.setNamespaceAware(true)` part in my previous code, explaining the exception raised back then.

Problem solved!